# Finishing Bejeweled game in Java (Class Project)

Tags: java

I'm a sophomore computer science major, working on my second class in Java. For our fifth project, I have to design a game like Bejeweled from scratch in Java. The project is nothing too difficult, but it's definitely been turning gears in my brain to keep this program as simple and efficient as possible.

Right now I'm a little stuck on getting the actual selection process working, hindering me from moving onto the point system and actual game-play of the game. In my event listener which implements the `MouseListener`, I have it set up to translate the point clicked into the row and column of the gem. From here, I have an `ArrayList` set-up to save `Dimension` variables, `gem1` and `gem2`. I also have a double array of booleans called `selections`. Depending on whether or not the `ArrayList` contains the specified gems, the listener should make the appropriate element in the `selections` double array true or false, ie selected or deselected. I've been toiling over this problem for too long, and I also have a cold that is making my life hell, and I'm having a bit of mental blockage.

If you see any quirks with my code or possible solutions to the selection issue, that would be greatly appreciated! I'm still learning and finding new, better ways to put my ideas into code, and the best way to do so is from criticism, so have at it I suppose! Thank you so much for your time. :)

EDIT: I know there are a lot of unfinished pieces left in the code, but it's a work in-progress. If you see something that's obviously not in use yet, don't worry about it.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Bejeweled extends JPanel{
// Utilities
static Random ran = new Random();
private Timer t;

// Board and Dimensions
public static int BOARD_SIZE = 10, DEFAULT_SIZE = 400,
        size = DEFAULT_SIZE/BOARD_SIZE;
static int[][] board;

// Gem Selection
final int CIRCLE = 0, SQUARE = 1, TRIANGLE = 2, HEXAGON = 3, OCTOGON = 4,
        DIAMOND = 5, RHOMBUS = 6;
public static boolean[][] selections;
public static ArrayList<Dimension> gems;
Dimension gem1, gem2;

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Bejeweled");
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel boardPane = new JPanel();
    boardPane.add(new Bejeweled());
    JPanel UI = new JPanel();
    JButton btn = new JButton("New Game");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Object newgame = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(f,
                    "Are you sure you want to start a new game?", "New Game?",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                    null, null, null);
            if(newgame.equals(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)){
                for(int r = 0; r < BOARD_SIZE; r++)
                    for(int c = 0; c < BOARD_SIZE; c++){
                        board[r][c] = ran.nextInt(7);
                        selections[r][c] = false;
                    }
                gems.clear();
                boardPane.repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    JTextPane coor1 = new JTextPane(), coor2 = new JTextPane();
    coor1.setText("Gem 1 Coords");
    coor2.setText("Gem 2 Coords");
    UI.add(coor1);
    UI.add(coor2);
    UI.add(btn);
    UI.setBackground(Color.black);
    JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
            boardPane, UI);
    f.setContentPane(pane);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public Bejeweled(){
    // Initialize variables
    t = new Timer();
    board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    selections = new boolean[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    gems = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
    gems.clear();

    // Set-up board and selections
    for(int r = 0; r < BOARD_SIZE; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < BOARD_SIZE; c++){
            board[r][c] = ran.nextInt(7);
            selections[r][c] = false;
        }

    addMouseListener(new EventListener());
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_SIZE, DEFAULT_SIZE));
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics p){
    super.paintComponent(p);
    size = getWidth()/BOARD_SIZE;

    for(int r = 0; r < BOARD_SIZE; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < BOARD_SIZE; c++){
            if(board[r][c] == CIRCLE){
                p.setColor(Color.white);
                p.fillOval((size*c)+2, (size*r)+2, size-4, size-4);
                if(selections[r][c] == true){
                    Graphics2D p2 = (Graphics2D) p;
                    p2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                    p2.setColor(new Color(210,210,50));
                    p2.drawRect(size*c, size*r, size, size);
                }
            }
            else if(board[r][c] == SQUARE){
                p.setColor(Color.red);
                p.fillRoundRect((size*c)+2, (size*r)+2, size-4, size-4,
                        size/4, size/4);
                if(selections[r][c] == true){
                    Graphics2D p2 = (Graphics2D) p;
                    p2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                    p2.setColor(new Color(210,210,50));
                    p2.drawRect(size*c, size*r, size, size);
                }
            }
            else if(board[r][c] == TRIANGLE){
                int[] xTriangle = {(size*c)+2, (size*(c+1))-size/2,
                        (size*(c+1))-2};
                int[] yTriangle = {(size*(r+1))-2, (size*r)+2, (size*(r+1))-2};
                p.setColor(Color.green);
                p.fillPolygon(xTriangle, yTriangle, xTriangle.length);
                if(selections[r][c] == true){
                    Graphics2D p2 = (Graphics2D) p;
                    p2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                    p2.setColor(new Color(210,210,50));
                    p2.drawRect(size*c, size*r, size, size);
                }
            }
            else if(board[r][c] == HEXAGON){
                int[] xHexagon = {(size*c)+2, (size*(c+1))-((size*3)/4),
                        (size*(c+1))-size/4, (size*(c+1))-2,
                        (size*(c+1))-size/4, (size*(c+1))-((size*3)/4)};
                int[] yHexagon = {(size*(r+1))-size/2, (size*r)+2,
                        (size*r)+2, (size*(r+1))-size/2, (size*(r+1))-2,
                        (size*(r+1))-2};
                p.setColor(Color.yellow);
                p.fillPolygon(xHexagon, yHexagon, xHexagon.length);
                if(selections[r][c] == true){
                    Graphics2D p2 = (Graphics2D) p;
                    p2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                    p2.setColor(new Color(210,210,50));
                    p2.drawRect(size*c, size*r, size, size);
                }
            }
            else if(board[r][c] == OCTOGON){
                int[] xOctogon = {(size*c)+2, (size*c)+2,
                        (size*(c+1))-((size*3)/4), (size*(c+1))-size/4,
                        (size*(c+1))-2, (size*(c+1))-2, (size*(c+1))-size/4,
                        (size*(c+1))-((size*3)/4)};
                int[] yOctogon = {(size*(r+1))-size/4,
                        (size*(r+1))-((size*3)/4), (size*r)+2, (size*r)+2,
                        (size*(r+1))-((size*3)/4), (size*(r+1))-size/4,
                        (size*(r+1))-2, (size*(r+1))-2};
                p.setColor(Color.blue);
                p.fillPolygon(xOctogon, yOctogon, xOctogon.length);
                if(selections[r][c] == true){
                    Graphics2D p2 = (Graphics2D) p;
                    p2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                    p2.setColor(new Color(210,210,50));
                    p2.drawRect(size*c, size*r, size, size);
                }
            }
            else if(board[r][c] == DIAMOND){
                int[] xDiamond = {(size*c)+2, (size*(c+1))-((size*3)/4),
                        (size*(c+1))-size/4, (size*(c+1))-2,
                        (size*(c+1))-size/2};
                int[] yDiamond = {(size*(r+1))-((size*3)/4), (size*r)+2,
                        (size*r)+2, (size*(r+1))-((size*3)/4), (size*(r+1))-2};
                p.setColor(Color.cyan);
                p.fillPolygon(xDiamond, yDiamond, xDiamond.length);
                if(selections[r][c] == true){
                    Graphics2D p2 = (Graphics2D) p;
                    p2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                    p2.setColor(new Color(210,210,50));
                    p2.drawRect(size*c, size*r, size, size);
                }
            }
            else if(board[r][c] == RHOMBUS){
                int[] xRhombus = {(size*c)+2, (size*(c+1))-size/2,
                        (size*(c+1))-2, (size*(c+1))-size/2};
                int[] yRhombus = {(size*(r+1))-size/2, (size*r)+2,
                        (size*(r+1))-size/2, (size*(r+1))-2};
                p.setColor(Color.magenta);
                p.fillPolygon(xRhombus, yRhombus, xRhombus.length);
                if(selections[r][c] == true){
                    Graphics2D p2 = (Graphics2D) p;
                    p2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                    p2.setColor(new Color(210,210,50));
                    p2.drawRect(size*c, size*r, size, size);
                }
            }
        }
}
private class EventListener implements MouseListener, ActionListener{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        int col = e.getX()/size, row = e.getY()/size;
        if(!gems.contains(gem1)){
            if(selections[row][col] != true){
                selections[row][col] = true;
                gem1 = new Dimension(row, col);
                gems.add(gem1);
            }
        }
        else if(gems.contains(gem1)){
            if(selections[row][col] = true){
                selections[row][col] = false;
                gems.remove(gem1);
            }
            else if(selections[row][col] = false){
                gem2 = new Dimension(row,col);
                gems.add(gem2);
                if(gem1 == new Dimension(gem2.width+1,gem2.height)){

                }
                else if(gem1 == new Dimension(gem2.width-1,gem2.height)){

                }
                else if(gem1 == new Dimension(gem2.width,gem2.height+1)){

                }
                else if(gem1 == new Dimension(gem2.width,gem2.height-1)){

                }
                else{
                    selections[gem1.width][gem1.height] = false;
                    gems.clear();
                    gem1 = new Dimension(row, col);
                    gems.add(gem1);
                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }

    // Unused implemented methods
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
}
```

Comment: Bejeweled, if I remember correctly, seems to have at most one element selected at a time. If second one becomes "selected" it just indicates move action. I didn't try reading the code, but simply having a variable `selectedJewel` should suffice, with it being null when nothing is selected yet.

Comment: Also - this site is for solving programming problems, dealing with stuff that doesn't work or not knowing how to make stuff work. I recommend http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for the constructive criticism of the parts that work but could be written better.